# FMOD play overlapping sounds

Tags: c, audio, fmod

This may be a build in feature of FMOD, but I'd like to see if i can override it.

When playing a SOUND with FMOD_System_PlaySound,

```
FMOD_System_PlaySound( system, FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, SOUND, false, &channel ) ;
```

(YES I use the C api ;) )

If you've ALREADY started playing SOUND, then what happens is the original one is STOPPED and SOUND starts over again.

The effect is the original sound gets "cut off". I don't want that, I want SOUND to overlap itself... I want another "instance" of the sound to start playing without affecting the original sound that's already playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAIT, NEVERMIND.

I had loaded the sound with FMOD_CREATESTREAM, which is why it kept starting the sound over again.

Carry on.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing you are, what was your solution when creating the sound?

Comment: Do not use the `FMOD_CREATESTREAM` flag when creating your sound